# Chebyshev inequality for bounding sum of dice rolls

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $S$ be the sum of $100$ fair dice rolls. Use
> Chebyshev’s inequality to bound $\mathbb{P}(S ≥ 380)$.

One version of Chebyshev's inequality states that
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}}$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ correspond to the mean and variance of $X$, respectively.

First, we can show that  $\mathbb{E}[S] =  350$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S) \approx 291.66$. Then, we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(S ≥ 380) = \mathbb{P}(S-350 ≥ 30)$$

I am a bit stuck here. Since $S \in \{100,...,600 \}$, we know that $S-350$ can take on both positive and negative values, so we can't just put an absolute value in this expression.

The solution, according to the book, is $\mathbb{P}(S \geq 380) \leq 0.324.$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have
$$\Pr(S \geq 380) \leq \Pr(S \geq 380) + \Pr(S \leq 320) = \Pr(|S - 350| \geq 30) \leq \operatorname{Var}(S) / 30^2 \approx 0.324$$
so this is probably the bound your book is looking for.

Comment: Ah, true, thank you :)